# Can login on Ubuntu on Wayland, but not on normal Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, login, wayland

I've recently been experiencing an odd login loop on Ubuntu. I can login on Ubuntu on Wayland (though I'd prefer not to), but whenever I try to login on the default "Ubuntu" setting, it fails in a black screen and goes back to the initial gdm3 login screen. I've tried the methods in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) question, but I haven't been able to get any of the methods to work. I use a laptop that uses Intel's Integrated Graphics, so it isn't an Nvidia driver problem like so many people answered in the linked post, but it also doesn't seem to be a permission problem, because I've gone through and checked every file permission relating to login. I added a new user, and am able to use both Wayland and the default "Ubuntu" setting fine, which means that it's isolated within my own user. I've gone through and checked logs, but I'm not exactly sure how to read them, so I just know that nothing in particular stood out to me. I've also tried the `sudo startx` method, but that has some weird effects on the icon and font scale.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this might be a bit late here, but `sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop` helped me. Looks like a `sudo apt autoremove` got a little overzealous.